# Is there a way to have one to many + one to many query in one result in group by?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I know the title is confusing. I have an example below. I know how to do it with inline SELECTs, try to avoid that:

```
T1
id | title
1     a


T2
t1_id | title
1        a1
1        a2
1        a3


T3
t1_id | amount
1         10


The result set should be: t1.id, group_concat(t2.title) , sum(t3.amount)
                            1   | a1,a2,a3 |                   10
```

Comment: To clarify, inline SELECT including like `select T1.*, (select group_concat(t2.title) from t2 where t2.t1_id=t1.id)` ?

Comment: @ajreal - yes, that is correct

Comment: For reference, what you call an "inline select" is more commonly referred to as a "subquery."

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select t2.t1_id, group_concat(t2.title), t3.amount
from t2
join t3 on t2.t1_id = t3.t1_id
group by t2.t1_id, t3.amount
```

Comment: This will return `30` rather than `10` too

Comment: Oh, he said SUM so I thought it's what he wanted. I've edited the SQL that might work.

Comment: The OP wants the sum but they don't want the same row to be counted multiple times purely as a by product of the join on the other table...

Comment: So t3 is not normalized? 
Meaning, can there be multiple entries/records for single t1_id with different amount?

Comment: @suhprano It is 100% normalized. Because the join of t2 and t2 will produce 3 entries, for which one copy of t3 will be attached, the sum will give 30 rather then what I need (10).

Comment: @Itay Moav Then did you try adding the AMOUNT column in the Group BY clause?